# Font list not refreshing in apps in debian

Tags: debian, fonts, fontconfig

I copied a bunch of .ttf and otf fonts into ~/.fonts, made sure permissions where set to my user/group and ran fc-cache ~/.fonts.

Opened up GIMP and Geany but the fonts aren't available. Any idea what's up?